# What are steps to migrate magento from enterprise edition to community edition?

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, migrate

I'm working on a magento Enterprise edition store and I want to migrate it to Community Edition.

I'm new to magento, please help me with some steps that I can follow to migrate EE to CE.

Could you please provide some ideas?

Comment: What version of Enterprise is your existing store in?

Comment: It's Magento ver. 1.9.1.1

Answer (score 0):

In my mind there are two different approaches.

You can start fresh with a new community install and bring over your code and design modifications and then your data.

Or you can try to downgrade your installation by "upgrading" to the latest version of community.

The way to go would depend on what modifications or customizations are in place

Answer (score 0):

Not all data can be moved as some of the tables and fields are not in community edition.

Steps suggested:
1. Install fresh magento community version.
2. Copy theme folder from ent site and paste in communiyt site.this will probably break at places and you will have to fill.
3. Magento has data import export system so use that to import products.
4. Similarly apply import export for customer(You might have to go with some 3rd party code for this).
5. Apply configuration via admin.

I am not sure whether you want to move order data too.This part is going to be complex.

Answer (score 0):

See https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6706/how-to-migrate-from-enterprise-edition-to-community-edition

Yanted has written a fabulous guide to this - some of the EE features in >= 1.13 actually make upgrades a little more painful than the below writeup would lead you to believe. As Marius points out in the comments that all passwords will have to be reset as encryption methods are handled differently between EE/CE.

See the blog for more details.

http://blog.yanted.com/2014/02/21/downgrading-magento-enterprise-to-community/

Original post:

Migrating is actually very easy - point your CE codebase at your production database. There's little more to it than that (see below for some folder removal information).

If you're using a well-built EE-compatible theme it should be backward compatible.

Here are some little-known EE features you'll need to watch out for when downgrading to Community:

No access to Customer Attributes from Admin Panel
Customer segments will go away
Catalog events, private sales, Invitations etc. will go away
CMS hierarchies are not supported in CE
Banners are not supported in CE
RMA - people always seem to forget about RMA (information will be resident in db)
Admin Logging information will be inaccessible (still resident in db)
If you have a large portion of your CMS built in EE I recommend you take a very thorough and methodical approach and make sure that your new CE theme (or backwardly-compatible EE theme) support the data that is still resident.

I also suggest not dropping any tables from the db prefixed with enterprise - as well as not removing any enterprise folders from your 3rd party themes. These are not considered as part of the EE install and you should take them along with you when you leave. You will need to remove the files and folders from the following locations:

app/code/core/Enterprise
app/design/frontend/enterprise
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/enterprise
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/enterprise
skin/adminhtml/default/enterprise
skin/frontend/enterprise
app/etc/modules/Enterprise_*.xml
js/enterprise
LICENSE_EE.txt
LICENSE_EE.html
And of course, you need to consider the real biggie: Full Page Cache. I highly recommend that you find a decent 3rd party Full Page cache.

Best of luck!